# not equals operator(!=) not working in python string comparison

Tags: python, string

I am trying to compare two `strings` in `python 3.6` and if they are not equal then print a message and exit. My current code is:

```
location = 'United States of America'
if location.lower() != 'united states of america' or location.lower() != 'usa':
    print('Location was different = {}'.format(location.lower()))
    sys.exit()
else:
    #do something
```

But the above code is not able to match the two strings and even though they are equal, it enters the loop and prints that they are different. I know its some silly mistake that I am making but unable to figure it out.

Comment: of course it will enter it, `'United States of America'.lower() != 'usa'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your condition:

```
if location.lower() != 'united states of america' or location.lower() != 'usa':
```

will never be `False`, since `location.lower()` can't be 2 different strings at the same time.

I suspect you want:

```
if location.lower() != 'united states of america' and location.lower() != 'usa':
```

Comment: even better: `if location.lower() not in ('united states', 'usa'):`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an AND condition instead of a OR condition in your if statement. If you change that you should be set